# Enforcing NSTableView only on selected row

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nscombobox

I'm building a view-based NSTableView with editable row columns. After user finishes editing a row and then selects another row using mouse/keyboard I want to prompt user asking if row just changed should be saved. I was able to get this working by processing NSTableViewDelegate shouldSelectRow notification - I can look at currently selected row and if changed prompt the user.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    // if tableView.selectedRow has changed prompt user to save first

    return true
}
```

My problems started when I added a NSComboBox column to the table. Now user can simply select value in the combo box using the mouse in *another* row by clicking the arrow button and selecting value from drop down. This does not change the selected row of the table. So I don't get shouldSelectRow notification.

My problem will be solved if somehow I can also select the row in which the combo box down arrow is being clicked at the same time. This should deliver a notification to me and then it should work. I looked at implementing NSComboBoxDelegate to get informed when value selection was changing in a combo box, but in that notification I get no information on which row the combo box is.

How can I also change the selection to the row where the combo box arrow button is being clicked?

Here's my tableView method

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var cellView: NSTableCellView
        cellView  = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

        if let transaction = account?.transactions[row] {
            switch tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue {
            case Column.date.rawValue?:
                cellView.textField?.stringValue = Date.fromDate(transaction.date)
            case Column.description.rawValue?:
                cellView.textField?.stringValue = transaction.desc
            case Column.type.rawValue?:
                var typeCombo = cellView.subviews[0] as! NSComboBox
                switch transaction.type {
                case .spend:
                    typeCombo.selectItem(withObjectValue: TransactionType.spend.rawValue)
                case .receive:
                    typeCombo.selectItem(withObjectValue: TransactionType.receive.rawValue)
                }
            case Column.amount.rawValue?:
                cellView.textField?.doubleValue = transaction.amount
            default:
                print("Default... - \(tableColumn?.identifier)")
                break
            }
        }

        return cellView
    }
```

Ideally what i would like it to prevent the combo box in other row from being clicked/editable unless user selects that row first. This is what I'm trying to accomplish now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get button's row in view based table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202813/get-buttons-row-in-view-based-table)

Comment: Show your tableView objectValueFor tableColumn delegate method.

Comment: I am not using objectValueFor, I'm using tableView. Code too long to paste here, will try in separate entry.